My converted PWA does not ask user for permission to turn location services on
I've used Oracle APEX on Oracle always free cloud services to develop a progressive web app - PWA. Then used webIntoApp.com to generate .APK and .abb files to be able to install my PWA on android phones. My PWA has buttons that gets the current user location using navigator.geolocation api. The buttons works well in the web app and if I installed the app on android phones through the feature that Oracle APEX provides ("Install app" button that enables users to install the app on their devices). But when I install the .APK that was provided by WebIntoApp.com, clicking the button don't turn on the location services or ask the user for permission to turn it on. Actually, It asks the user for only one time but do not turn the location services on when user allow it. Clicking the buttons again does nothing. It neither ask for a permission or turn the location services on. What could be the reason for that?
Thanks a lot
Tried contacting them with no response.

I suggest you ask this question in the official oracle APEX forum.

It has nothing to do with APEX. It works fine as a web app or PWA when installed on phones using APEX.
